# Is the union of less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ (closed) sets of empty interior, a set of empty interior?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Baire category theorem gives this result for countable unions. But what can be said about unions of size less than $2^{\aleph_0}$?

I only need this to be true in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for my purposes.

Strictly speaking, I only need the following: An open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not the union of less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ straight lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meager sets, i.e. countable union of closed nowhere dense sets, have empty interior as you mentioned above.

The covering number of the meager ideal is the smallest cardinality $\kappa$ so that $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of $\kappa$ many meager set.

If the covering number of the meager ideal is  less than $2^{\aleph_0}$, then $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ meager sets. Replacing each meager set with the countably many closed nowhere dense set forming it will give you a less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ union of closed nowhere dense sets with empty interior.

This situation can occur but of course requires the failure of the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: More strongly,it requires negating MA (Martin's Axiom).

Answer (score 8):

Re: Strictly speaking, I only need the following: An open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not the union of less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ straight lines.

This is true since for example: Every open set in plane contains a circle. And less than continuum lines cannot cover a circle.

Comment: +1. Elaborating on the last line for the OP, note that each line intersects a given circle in at most two points ...